# Is there a show attribute in react -popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup

There is a trigger button in react popup, does it have show attribute ?

```
<Popup trigger={<button> Trigger</button>} position="right center">
<div>Popup content here !!</div>
</Popup>
```

I mean, my requiremnt is to show the popup when an event happens (when i click a cell in react table- triggers goes to a onclick function, if i can do somethnig in onclick to triggr the popup)

Something like:

```
<Popup show=this.state.showpopup position="right center">
<div>Popup content here !!</div>
</Popup>
```

this.state.showpopup will be set from onclick

Answer (score 0):

The Popup has a prop called *open* which takes a boolean.
try:

```
open={this.state.showpopup}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show the popup without using trigger props,
Try this

```
function component() {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    return (
        <Fragment>
              <button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Trigger</button>
              <Popup modal={showModal} position="right center">
                     <div>Popup content here !!</div>
              </Popup>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```